# PHP string to associative array?

Tags: php

How do I create an associative array with the following string?`size:3|order_by:date|order:ASC|post_type:post`
to

```
Array
(
  "size" => 3,
  "order_by" => "date",
  "order" => "ASC",
  "post_type" => "post"
)
```

Comment: You need to do more research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
$str = 'size:3|order_by:date|order:ASC|post_type:post';

$arr = explode('|', $str);

foreach ( $arr as $a){
    $t = explode(':', $a);
    $new[$t[0]] = $t[1];
}

print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [size] => 3
    [order_by] => date
    [order] => ASC
    [post_type] => post
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
preg_match_all("/([^:|]+):([^\|]+)/", $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

- `([^:|]+)` capture `()` one or more `+` not `^` characters `:` or `|` into match 1
- match a `:`
- `([^\|]+)` capture `()` one or more `+` not `^` characters `|` into match 2
- combine the matches

Comment: The trailing `\|` on your regex means it won't match `post_type:post`. Also note `|` does not need to be escaped in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to use the array_reduce PHP function like in the following snippet...

```php
<?php
$str = "size:3|order_by:date|order:ASC|post_type:post";
$arr = array_reduce(explode('|', $str), function ($carry, $item) {
    $itemArr = explode(':', $item);
    if (count($itemArr) == 2) {
        $carry[$itemArr[0]] = $itemArr[1];
        return $carry;
    }
}, []);

print_r($arr);
```